# How to save a form state from a jquery that disables my submit button when timer ends?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, state

I have a javascript running in my site that runs down a timer to zero and then displays a message and disables my submit button to prevent more data being inputted into my database. I have got it to disable the submit button when the timer finishes however when the page is reloaded it enables the submit button. I know i need to save the form state however i dont know how i would go about this?

This is my part of my javascript that disables

```
function CountBack(secs) {
if (secs < 0) {
document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
$("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");


return;
```

This is my form

```
<form id="MakeBid" action="MakeBid.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="propertyID" value ="1"/>
<div>Bid Now <input type="text" name="pricesoldfor"/></div> 
<input id = "submit" input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use cookie to save your state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

1. Keep the state on the server.
2. Before sending the form to the client, check if (s)he is allowed to write to your database.
3. Send the form with embedded parameter like `MyForm.noSubmit = true;`.
4. Optionally - poll the server and check if it accepts more data.

So, assuming you have PHP on the server, you get *something* like this:

```
var MyForm.noSubmit = <?php echo ($MyDB->acceptsData()) ? "false" : "true"; ?>
```

or

```
<input <?php if (!$MyDB->acceptsData()) {echo "disabled=\"disabled\"";} ?> />
```

Depends on your implementation of course.

The above suggestion will work on page reload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.serialize()` method of jquery to store the state of your form. Then you can use deserialize plugin to deserialize(restore) your form

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/deserialize

Store your form

```
var formState = $("#MakeBid").serialize();
```

Then store the `formState` as a string in cookie. Once the page is reloaded, you can read the formState from cookie and deserialize the form.

restore form:

```
$("#MakeBid").deserialize(formState ,
callback: function(name,value){
$('input[name="'+name+'"]').val(value);
});
```

Comment: How will i store the formstate as a string as a cookie? I think this answer will be the one that works just seems fairly complex

Comment: formState is already a string. So just store it in cookie as you would store any other thing! And storing this value in cookie is not advisable. Because the client can always clear the cookies! May be you can store the formState in your server!

Answer (score 0):

Include this file in your HTML page: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

And then, after the time spent set a cookie:
`$.cookie('block','1')`

At the opening of your page, you can activate or deactivate the submit with the following

```
jQuery(function($){
  if($.cookie('block'))
    $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

But keep in mind this method is only client side, so don't use it to secure your website, if you want to prevent a form to be posted, do it server side.

**EDIT:** Here [the full solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ErkA3/)

```
var bidDuration = 10000
  , bidFinishedMessage = "C'est fini !!";

jQuery(function($){        
  var finishBid = function() {
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#cntdwn").html(bidFinishedMessage);
    $.cookie('blockBid','1');
  };

  if($.cookie('blockBid'))
    $('#submit').attr("disabled","disabled");

  setTimeout(finishBid, bidDuration);
});
```

​

Comment: I tried this option, but it didnt seem to work i saved the js file and added the code to my js however it didnt seem to stop the submit button reappearing.

Comment: Check this link, the script I made is working perfectly ;) http://jsfiddle.net/ErkA3/

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely enable the submit or not on the **server-side**. If enough datas have been submitted, disable the form on the server-side and disable listening to it too, you won't have to worry about it.

Example in pseudo-code:

```
If enough datas are in the database, don't write to it and leave the script
Else write normally, it means the countdown's not reached the end
```

Because even if the form is disabled, I can still enable it and send you some datas.

**Never trust the client.**

Comment: I agree with your answer however i want the user to see that they cant bid anymore otherwise they will be bidding and the auction would of ended. Appreciate your response though

Comment: Which is why you can still show the disabled form. And stop processing it on the server too.

Comment: Florian has a point. The state should be saved on the server. Keep in mind that the user can submit information without using your form. Now for the button: when serving your page - check if your database is ready to accept the input and if not, disable the submit button.